# What does it mean open mode in Virt-Manager?

Tags: linux, networking, virtualization, virt-manager

Virt-Manager offers a network "open mode". Could you tell me what does it  mean?

For example:

[image]

I use Fedora 26 with virt-manager 1.4.2